# Is there a way to write to a Google docs spreadsheet from the Linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a cron job that exports some data to CSV every day.  Is it possible to write this data directly to a Google doc (spreadsheet) from the Linux shell (Ubuntu)?

Comment: This might help https://code.google.com/p/googlecl/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For that you have the [Google Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/)

Example code at [Write to a Google Spreadsheet from a Python script](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/write-google-spreadsheet-from-python/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did it with the provided python script, and manage to install it locally **without root rights**.